# How to correctly handle foreach loops as well as incremented dynamic content from array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm a beginner coder and I continuously get stuck at simply array and output handling.

I have been sitting with this for a  day without attempting to post it here but frustration got me lol, I'm trying to print out all the algos the are being outputted. I'll explain:

```
$w = file_get_contents(utf8_encode($nna->nice_url.$ns->method1.$cur_addy))
```

the `$w` variable fetches information from the url https://nicehash.com/api?method=stats.provider&addr=BTCaddyhere. It then will have a similar output the bellow.

```
{  
   "result":{  
      "stats":[  
         {  
            "balance":"0.00036893",
            "rejected_speed":"0",
            "algo":5,
            "accepted_speed":"0"
         },
         {  
            "balance":"0.00000033",
            "rejected_speed":"0",
            "algo":7,
            "accepted_speed":"0"
         },
      ],
      "payments":[  

      ],
      "addr":"14PvYoNEGttZt2JBZV9mHdr"
   },
   "method":"stats.provider"
}
```

Now this output is dynamic as if I am mining only using Lyra2re2 it will display only number 14 under algo. Once the profitability changes it will swop algos and display its profit by adding it to the output.

I have tried to display only the available numbers which are outputted by method1's url with "

```
foreach ($na->algo as $k => $v) {
    print $ss['result']['stats'][$k++]['algo']."<br />";
    print $ss['result']['stats'][$k++]['balance']."<br />";
}
```

I have tried incrementing the offset which works 100% and displays the correct number for each algo that is collected, although it will display the proper algo but the undefined variables which gets created because it cannot find the output to match the algo array so it outputs the number as an undefined variable.

Basically I would like to create a table for the stats and let it increment itself when the output from the api changes and adds the additional algo's to the list as well as display accepted_speed rejected_speed so on. I'm not sure if this array is an efficient way to assign the numbers to its string ?

Bellow you will find my 3 php pages : 1.index.php, 2.class.inc.php, 3.functions.inc.php

Just a thought, would putting the json data into a MySQL db and let that update the information and simply use php to display whats in that db ? only if its possible to update the db in realtime

Any help would be appreciated :). 
Thanks

```html
//index.php page below 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
//files required
require_once('config.inc.php');
require_once('class.inc.php');
require_once('functions.inc.php');
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="stats_provider">
   <form action="" method="POST">
    <label>BTC ADDR: </label>
    <input type="text" name="btc_addr" style="min-width: 32px; width: 290px; padding-left: 3px;" placeholder="EG: 14i97joNEGttZt2JBZLU7HdrjxevFukjNG7" />
    <button>Enter</button>
   </form>
  </div>
  <?php
   
    $n = get_btc_addy();
    if (isset($cur_addy)) {
     $ns = new methods();
     $nna = new nice_api();
     $w = file_get_contents(utf8_encode($nna->nice_url.$ns->method1.$cur_addy));
     $ss = json_decode($w, true);
     $na = new algos();
     foreach ($na->algo as $k => $v) {
         print $ss['result']['stats'][$k++]['algo']."<br />";
         print $ss['result']['stats'][$k++]['balance']."<br />";
     }


    }
   
  ?>
  <div id="current_api_version">
   <?php
    $ver = get_api_version();
    print "<p>Current API Version: ".$l."</p>";
   ?>
  </div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

```html
//Class.inc.php page

<?php
class nice_api {
 public $api_url = 'https://nicehash.com/api';
 public $nice_url = 'https://nicehash.com/';
}

class methods {

 public $method1 = 'api?method=stats.provider&addr=';
 public $method1x = 'api?method=stats.provider.ex&';
 public $method2 = 'api?method=stats.global.current&';
 public $method3 = 'api?method=stats.global.24h&';
 public $method4 = 'api?method=stats.provider.workers&addr=';
 public $method5 = 'api?method=multialgo.info';
}

class algos {
 public $algo = array(
  0 => 'Scrypt',
  1 => 'SHA256',
  2 => 'ScryptNf',
  3 => 'X11',
  4 => 'X13',
  5 => 'Keccak',
  6 => 'X15',
  7 => 'Nist5',
  8 => 'NeoScrypt',
  9 => 'Lyra2RE',
  10 => 'WhirlpoolX',
  11 => 'Qubit',
  12 => 'Quark',
  13 => 'Axiom',
  14 => 'Lyra2REv2',
  15 => 'ScryptJaneNf16',
  16 => 'Blake256r8',
  17 => 'Blake256r14',
  18 => 'Blake256r8vnl',
  19 => 'Hodl',
  20 => 'DaggerHashimoto',
  21 => 'Decred',
  22 => 'Cryptonite',
  23 => 'Lbry',
  24 => 'Equihash',
  25 => 'Pascal',
  26 => 'X11 Ghost',
  27 => 'Sia',
  28 => 'Blake2s',
  29 => 'Skunk'
 );
}

?>
```

```html
//functions.inc.php

<?php
require_once('class.inc.php');

function get_api_version() {
 $url = new nice_api();
 $api_version = file_get_contents(utf8_encode($url->api_url));
 $api_ver = json_decode($api_version, true);
    global $l; 
    $l = $api_ver['result']['api_version'];
}

function get_btc_addy() {
 //dynamically change addy for each user
 if (isset($_POST['btc_addr'])) {
    $ibtc = $_POST['btc_addr'];
    global $cur_addy;
    $cur_addy = $ibtc;
   
 } 
}
?>
```

Comment: So much text... Your jsonarray is called $ss. And you loop $na. What is $na? It's not the json as far as I can see

Comment: $na->algo is looping through the array "algo" in class,inc.php which then will display the number for the algo which is produced by the json response. I will be making it display the string to the user though.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'll post what I think you need. Or at least what you can work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `foreach` something that I'm not sure what it is.
If you want to loop the Jason you do like this:

```
$w ='{  
"result":{  
  "stats":[  
     {  
        "balance":"0.00036893",
        "rejected_speed":"0",
        "algo":5,
        "accepted_speed":"0"
     },
     {  
        "balance":"0.00000033",
        "rejected_speed":"0",
        "algo":7,
        "accepted_speed":"0"
     },
     {  
        "balance":"0.00283658",
        "rejected_speed":"0",
        "algo":14,
        "accepted_speed":"0"
     },
     {  
        "balance":"0.00000186",
        "rejected_speed":"0",
        "algo":20,
        "accepted_speed":"0"
     },
     {  
        "balance":"0.00000003",
        "rejected_speed":"0",
        "algo":21,
        "accepted_speed":"0"
     },
     {  
        "balance":"0.0027542",
        "rejected_speed":"0",
        "algo":22,
        "accepted_speed":"0.00000067"
     },
     {  
        "balance":"0.00002058",
        "rejected_speed":"0",
        "algo":23,
        "accepted_speed":"0"
     },
     {  
        "balance":"0.00029013",
        "rejected_speed":"0",
        "algo":24,
        "accepted_speed":"0"
     },
     {  
        "balance":"0.00000006",
        "rejected_speed":"0",
        "algo":25,
        "accepted_speed":"0"
     },
     {  
        "balance":"0.00000001",
        "rejected_speed":"0",
        "algo":26,
        "accepted_speed":"0"
     },
     {  
        "balance":"0.00000039",
        "rejected_speed":"0",
        "algo":27,
        "accepted_speed":"0"
     },
     {  
        "balance":"0.00069389",
        "rejected_speed":"0",
        "algo":28,
        "accepted_speed":"0"
     }
  ],
  "payments":[  

  ],
  "addr":"14PvYoNEGttZt2JBZV9mHdr"
},
"method":"stats.provider"
}';

$ss = json_decode($w, true);
$na = new algos();
foreach ($ss['result']['stats'] as $k => $v) {
    print $na[$v['algo']]."<br />\n";
    print $v['balance']."<br />\n\n";
}
```

I `foreach` `$ss['result']['stats']` which means `$v = $ss['result']['stats']`.
That way `$v['algo']` outputs the `id` (or whatever it is).

https://3v4l.org/OLjUl

---

*And for your own sake use real variable names.

This mess will get out of hands in no time with `$w`, `$ss` and `$n` and all that.*

Comment: that works perfectly :). if I would like to print out the string instead of the number how would I go about doing that using the array?

Comment: You mean the algo thing in the class? I will give it a try. Give me a minute.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type algos as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:35 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 35 ---> print $na[$v['algo']]."<br />\n";

Comment: @JamesBond Seems as your new algos() isn't working as it should. Can you replace that with the array, or is the class itself important? Like this: https://3v4l.org/uBZck

Comment: made it into a function and made the variable global, it works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this loop:

```
foreach ($na->algo as $k => $v) {
    print $ss['result']['stats'][$k++]['algo']."<br />";
    print $ss['result']['stats'][$k++]['balance']."<br />";
}
```

By this way:

```
foreach ($ss['result']['status'] as $s){
    print $na->algo[$s['algo']];
}
```

Comment: this worked wonders :) foreach ($ss['result']['stats'] as $s) {
         print "Algo: ".$na->algo[$s['algo']]."<br />";
         print "Balance: ".$s['balance']."<br />";
         print "AC Speed: ".$s['accepted_speed']."<br />";
         print "RJ Speed: ".$s['rejected_speed']."<br /><hr>";
     }